# Specifying feature types for BayesianMinimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'd like to use Bayesian optimization over a pair of features, one nominal, one numerical. If I do something like this:

```
bo = BayesianMinimization[Null, {{"A", 10}, {"B", 100}}, 
InitialEvaluationHistory -> {{"A", 100} -> 100, {"B", 10} -> 10}, 
MaxIterations -> 0];
```

And look at the resulting `PredictorFunction` by evaluating `bo["PredictorFunction"]`, I see that it defaults to a `text` feature type for the first entry, which is incorrect (they're distinct categories and it shouldn't try to interpolate in text-space.) `Predict` and friends handle this using the `FeatureTypes` option, and checking the `Options` of `BayesianMinimization`, I see that `FeatureTypes` is a valid, albeit undocumented, option. However, it seems to have no effect, as modifying the above to the following:

```
bo=BayesianMinimization[Null,{{"A",10},{"B",100}},InitialEvaluationHistory->  
{{"A",100}->100,{"B",10}->10},MaxIterations->0,FeatureTypes->
{"Nominal","Numerical"}];
```

still results in a `PredictorFunction` whose first argument is of type `text` instead of `nominal`.

And the behavior is a little erratic. For example this:

```
bo = BayesianMinimization[<|{"A", 10.} -> 10, {"B", 100.} -> 
100|>[#] &, {{"A", 10.}, {"B", 100.}}, MaxIterations -> 2]
```

automatically defaults to a `nominal` feature for the first entry, so how it decides whether a feature is `text` or `nominal` seems arbitrary. This latter example doesn't solve my problem because I don't want to supply `BayesianMinimization` with a function that it evaluates (all the evaluations are done off-line and are being fed to `BayesianMinimization` through `InitialEvaluationHistory` instead of allowing it to directly evaluate a function.)